# loading a VCF file into memory, and then, reading it with pyvcf

Tags: python, bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format

I am new in python and bioinformatics.

I am trying to first load a VCF file into the memory, and then parse it with the pyvcf library, but I am getting this error:"IndexError: list index out of range* "
I have searched in the internet, but I didn't find any answers.

By the way, the code is:

```
import mmap
import vcf
file_chr_mt_vcf = 'ALL.chrMT.phase3_callmom-v0_4.20130502.genotypes.vcf'
chr_mt = open(file_chr_mt_vcf, 'rb')
m = mmap.mmap(chr_mt.fileno(), 0, access = True)
chr_mt = vcf.Reader(m)
for i in chr_mt:
    print i.is_snp
```

What should I do? Is there any better way to do this?

It should be mentioned that changing the pyvcf library and move to another one is impossible because I have written hundreds of lines of code to do some tasks. I just want to load the vcf file into memory and then do those tasks with pyvcf.

Comment: At which line are you getting the error? Did you checked that the file was properly opened and mmapped? Are you sure that the `vcf.Reader()` can be instantiated with a memory address instead of a file?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
Well, at the `for` loop line I am getting this error. I think that `vcf.Reader` cannot be instantiated with a memory address. Still, I'm not sure. If it couldn't be instantiated with a memory address, is there anything that I can do to load my file to RAM and then open it with`vcf.Reader()` ?

Comment: If it cannot be instantiated with a memory address, try with the usual option: give it a file, directly. Or read the documentation to see which are your options. I'm just guessing. BTW, you are going to do a sequential traversal of the whole file, mapping the file will not give you any gain.

Comment: Mapping the file will reduce the total run time of the program because the pyvcf library is really slow.

Comment: Do a benchmark with the stated conditions (sequential read of the whole file) and convince yourself about reality.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have to recheck the "m = mmap.mmap(chr_mt.fileno(), 0, access = True)" code. If this throws error, the vcf will not be read in the following line of code.
Moreover, even if the vcf files reads, if you are trying to take each entry in vcf by performing for loop. You should try:

```
for record in chr_mt:
    print(record)
```

This is to check if the vcf is being read properly.
The word "record" used in for loop is I guess a default name.
Try this.